# How to batch delete files based on their checksum matching an existing list of checksums

Tags: windows, windows-7

1. Capable of deleting files whose checksum matches a set list of checksums
2. Must run on Windows 7
3. List to match against can take any format - text, XLS, CSV, etc.
4. Prefer to spend no more than $50

I'm looking for a means of deleting files based on their checksum matching a list of previously seen checksums in a text file or some other list.

The context is a large photo organization project where data will be coming to me from many sources, often with duplication. 95% of what's submitted will be deleted based on a human review of it. I'd like to generate a list of checksums of batch A when it's submitted and before a human looks through them. Then, when Batch B is submitted I can run it against that cumulative list of checksums and automatically delete anything in the list since it will already have been reviewed. I'll then add the remaining checksums to the list and review them, without wasting time reviewing those images that were already seen in Batch A.

I know I can do this by simply keeping a folder of the 95% of rejected photos instead of deleting them and then running a deduplicate program against them, but for storage and privacy purposes I prefer to delete them once they've been reviewed.

The best I've come up with so far is to generate an MD5 and filepath/name list of Batch B and then use an Access query to output a .bat file to delete any filepath/names whose associated MD5 matches the list from Batch A, but if there's a program out there that can do this natively I'd love to use it. Thanks in advance!